# Can I reduce the relative clause after 'since' to a phrase?

Tags: verbs, relative-clauses, whiz-deletion

The title might be confusing because I don't know how to phrase the question correctly. Here is an example:

> The Asian Games have been promoted in all aspects since the first Games *which were held* in 1951.

Can this be reduced to 
"The Asian Games have been promoted in all aspects since the first Games *held* in 1951"?

Comment: Or even shorter: "...since the first games of 1951."

Comment: There is a possibility of introducing ambiguity (The committee elections have always been carefully regulated since the first election held in 1951), but punctuation or context could resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

The word that refers to this type of reduction is ellipsis.

Ellipsis is fine here, but the punctuation is important.

If you say, "the first games held in 1951", it means that there were several games in 1951, and you are referring to the first of them.

What you want to say is, "the first games, held in 1951". Here, the addition of the comma makes the sentence mean what you want it to, that the first games were held in 1951.

This is essentially the difference between defining and non-defining relative clauses.